# ANT Galio browser perfomance issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, dom-events

I have a problem with performance optimization. Currently writing an application for copy machine on ANT Galio browser. The problem is that this does not allow to use the mousemove event, but an event mouseover works just fine. I had to write an invisible grid that movement senses. Since the browser does not know how to work with alpha channel had to use background with a picture in one transparent pixel. Browser only supports CSS2 and ecmaScript1.6. The problem is that the grid works fine but if it is serious loaded then the application begins to slow down, but if the same manipulations on the mousemove that all works well on the emulator but not working on the unit it self.

[image]

mouseover event handler:

```
function _onMouseOverSubTile (e) {
    var tempSubTile = e.target,
        myData = getData(tempSubTile),
        myGrid = myData.grid,
        myCallBack = myGrid.callBack;
    if (myCallBack) {
        var tempSubTile = e.target,
            mySubTile = myData.tile;
        subTileOffsetLeft = mySubTile.left,
        subTileOffsetTop = mySubTile.top;
        myCallBack(

          //x
          myGrid.viewPortOffsetLeft + 
          myGrid.layerLeft + 
          myGrid.currentTileOffsetLeft + .
          subTileOffsetLeft + 
          myGrid.subTileWidth / 2, 

          //y
          myGrid.viewPortOffsetTop + 
          myGrid.layerTop + 
          myGrid.currentTileOffsetTop + 
          subTileOffsetTop + myGrid.subTileHeight / 2);
    };
};
```

Here is the application:
http://jsfiddle.net/Greck_geek/xfg85Lzn/

Comment: Perhaps the browser freezes due to the fact that offset data are collected and which is the cause redraw the entire window. Interestingly if all calculations delay by a timer is it stops browser  to hang?

Answer (score 0):

The application is running slow due to the transparent pixel!!! If do not use it then all works fine.